# showing multiple rows from database in datagridview using entity framework

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I am trying to show multiple records from database in datagridview but I'm having only a single record all the time.
2 tables are involved in this query, from 1st table I acquire all the id's those fulfill the condition and from 2nd table I am getting the user information.
1st table is tblUsers_Roles and 2nd is tblUsers.
These tables have primary/foriegn key relationship.
Here is my code:

```
IEnumerable<tblUsers_Role> id = db.tblUsers_Role.Where(a => a.User_Role == selectRole);

foreach (var user in id)
{
    var userinfo = from b in db.tblUsers 
                   where b.User_Id == user.User_Id 
                   select new { b.First_Name, b.Last_Name, b.Status, b.Authenticated };

    dgvResults.DataSource = userinfo.ToList();
    dgvResults.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the grid in the loop. That is not going to work. Maybe something like this will work:

```
var userinfo =(from ur in db.tblUsers_Role
    join u in db.tblUsers
        on ur.User_Id equals u.User_Id 
    where ur.User_Role == selectRole
    select new
    {
        u.First_Name, 
        u.Last_Name, 
        u.Status, 
        u.Authenticated
    }).ToList();

dgvResults.DataSource = userinfo;
dgvResults.Show();
```

Or a alteretive would be like this:

```
 var roles=db.tblUsers_Role
             .Where(a => a.User_Role == selectRole)
             .Select (a =>a.User_Id).ToList();

var userinfo=
    (
        from u in db.tblUsers
        where roles.Contains(u.User_Id)
        select new
        {
            u.First_Name, 
            u.Last_Name, 
            u.Status, 
            u.Authenticated
        }
    ).ToList();

dgvResults.DataSource = userinfo;
dgvResults.Show();
```

Not as nice as the first one. But maybe you understand the concept.

Comment: i will:)
by the way first solution was beautiful!